# #if in the head of a freemarker templat

Tags: boolean, freemarker

I'm new to FTL so please excuse my ignorance on the language.

I'm trying to pull in a Google Survey script using the following code.

```
<%#if Page.ShowSurvey = 'true'%>
     <ui:include src="/includes/survey.jsp" /><%/#if%>
```

The code is being placed in the 'head' tags. When I go to test deploy the page, I'm receiving a server error.

Could someone shine some light on how to properly do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did this syntax come from? For starters, FTL uses `<#something ...>`, not `<%#something ...%>`. Also, call `<ui:include ...>` is just static text in FTL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Freemarker [conditional syntax](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_if.html) with the `@include_page` command:

```
<#assign c=JspTaglibs["http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"] />

<@c:if test="Page.ShowSurvey eq 'true'">  
  <@c:import url="/includes/survey.jsp" />  
</@c:if>
```

Comment: Upon regenerating the page, I received this error message.... include is not a user-defined directive. It is a freemarker.ext.dom.NodeListModel

Comment: Also, the major piece of the code is the ability to turn on or off. using a boolean method within the XSD.

Comment: That `@c.if` isn't the FTL conditional syntax, it's JSP JSTL core called from FTL. The FTL-ish way of writing that is simply `<#if Page.ShowSurvey>...</#if>`. Well, assuming `Page.ShowSurvey` is a boolean. Also note that the `JspTaglibs` thing only works if you invoke FreeMarker through the `freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet` extension.